# Add Email Signature to Email Notification Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am writing a code on Google Apps Script to send an email every time there is a new announcement made in my site. Here is the code for reference:

```js
var url_of_announcements_page = "https://sites.google.com/announcements"; 
var who_to_email = "emailaccount";

function emailAnnouncements(){
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url_of_announcements_page); 
  if(page.getPageType() == SitesApp.PageType.ANNOUNCEMENTS_PAGE){ 

    var announcements = page.getAnnouncements({ start: 0,
                                               max: 10,
                                               includeDrafts: false,
                                               includeDeleted: false});
    announcements.reverse();                                    
    for(var i in announcements) { 
      var ann = announcements[i]; 
      var updated = ann.getLastUpdated().getTime(); 
      if (updated > PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("last-update")){ 
        var options = {}; 

        options.htmlBody = Utilities.formatString("<h1><a href='%s'>%s</a></h1>%s", ann.getUrl(), ann.getTitle(), ann.getHtmlContent());

        MailApp.sendEmail(who_to_email, "Announcement - '"+ann.getTitle()+"'", ann.getTextContent()+"\n\n"+ann.getUrl(), options);

        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last-update',updated);
      }
    }
  }
}

function setup(){
 PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last-update',new Date().getTime());
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to add my gmail signature to the code. As when I send it with the script my signature is removed. Do I have to make my signature in the code or am i able to get my signature from gmail and automatically insert it at the end? Here is the line for the formatting of the email:

```js
MailApp.sendEmail(who_to_email, "Announcement - '"+ann.getTitle()+"'", ann.getTextContent()+"\n\n"+ann.getUrl(), options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Script cannot access user's signature: there is no method for that in MailApp, or [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app), or even in [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) accessible via Advanced Google Services.

In principle, you could use GmailApp to get a recent outgoing message and search its text for the signature contained after the last `--` found in message body. But this requires giving the script a lot more access (GmailApp can access, forward and delete existing email, unlike MailApp) and is error-prone (when text parsing fails, you might end up with an embarrassing fragment of text in your message).

Just append it directly:

```
var signature = "\n\n--\nFirstName LastName"; 
// ... 
MailApp.sendEmail(... +signature, options);
```

(By the way, Gmail web interface and Gmail mobile app have different user signatures in general, so having another one for script-generated messages doesn't seem unusual.)